# Merge columns together from multiples tables, columns not in order

Tags: sql-server, merge, union-all

I have 3 SELECT FROM and I would like to merge the 3 results in one table, I can't use one select*from and use JOIN for the 3 tables.

I can merge the tables using the A and B columns used as a Key.
I need to do a final UNION on the 3 merged tables where the columns are not in the same order.

Example :

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
FROM Table 
UNION ALL
(
   SELECT A, B, F, G FROM Stuff
   --JOIN?MERGE?WhatHere?
   SELECT A, B, E, C FROM otherStuff
   --JOIN?MERGE?WhatHere?
   SELECT A, B, D, H FROM otherstuffbis
   I --adding null value to columns
 )
```

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL-Server`? Pick one.

Comment: Sorry, Auto complete, sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
FROM Table 
UNION ALL
(


   SELECT 
   A, 
   B, 
   NULL AS c, 
   NULL AS D,
   NULL AS E,   
   F, 
   G ,
   NULL AS H,
   NULL AS I
   FROM [stuff]


   SELECT 
   A, 
   B, 
   c, 
   NULL AS D,
   E,   
   NULL AS F, 
   NULL AS G ,
   NULL AS H,
   NULL AS I
   FROM [otherStuff]

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
   A, 
   B, 
   NULL AS c, 
   NULL AS D,
   E,   
   NULL AS F, 
   NULL AS G ,
   H,
   NULL AS I
   FROM [otherstuffbis]


 ) A
```